# How to implement ZF2 View without using partialLoop view helper?

Tags: model-view-controller, view, zend-framework2

I have a pattern that I come across sufficiently often and I am looking for specifically a ZF2 (ZF3) way of solving this somewhat `N + 1`-related issue.

The following are excerpts from a single PHP file:

**Looping through DB records & building table rows with data**

Some number (say N) table rows are printed:

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < db_num_rows($result); $i ++)
{
    $row = db_fetch_array($result);
    ?>
<tr onclick="js_action(<?=$row['id']?>)">
    <td><?=$row['number']></td>
    <td><?=$row['company']?></td>
</tr>
<? } ?>
```

**A single embedded JS Script that needs to be printed only once**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function js_action(id)
{
    // some JS code
}
</script>
```

**Question**

I want to separate view generation from DB, and my main concern here is . . . do I use [`partialLoop`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.partial.html) view helper or skip it out entirely?

I can use `partialLoop` which will have me create files like this:

```
//controller
$this->partialLoop('filename', $arrayRows);

<!-- view -->
<td>$this->number</td>
<td>$this->company</td>
```

I don't see a point of creating a file so small just for this little loop.  What is a good way to implement the View Script in my case?

Answer (score 1):

The primary use-case for [`partialLoop`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.partial.html) is already mentioned in the documentation (emphasis added):

> The primary use is for **reusable** template fragments

The only reason to split markup into another template is for reusability. If you don't need to reuse the markup, there is no reason to do the extra mile and defining an extra template. This makes reading & maintaining the template only harder.

Instead it is perfectly fine to use a `foreach` loop in your view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function js_action(id)
{
    // some JS code
}
</script>
<table>
<?php foreach ($this->arrowRows as $row) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['number']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['company']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Even when you have this snippet arround a couple of times, it might make sense to keep it in place instead of creating a such small view script. For me it would seem like over-optimization.

I usually follow these principles:

- Only move something into a seperate template when I reuse it more than 2-3 times
- Only move code that contains more complex logic that `echo`ing some values into simple markup (e.g. conditional rendering)
- Simple markup can always be embedded even when it is re-used (e.g. simple tables with few classes)
- Never try to generalize partials where the parent view defines the behavior of the markup (e.g. the view defines extra classes to be used in the partial). This usually ends of making everything more complex and coupled than being helpfull.